# Android Studio Robolectric resource folder

Tags: android, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have a workspace in the android studio that consists of the app projects and dependency android library project.

I have a unit test in the app project that tests the class that loads the string from both app project resources and the dependency library project resources.

When I run the unit test in Roboletric I get resource not found exception when the tested class tries to load the string from the library project resources.

How to fix this issue? How do I specify both the app and the dependency library resource directories for Robolectric to use?

Comment: fix 1 - copy the resources to the app folder in a file called `duplications-for-tests.xml`. Fix 2 - override and provide your own test runner, then you can specify an "manifest" and tell robolectric where to look for resources

Comment: Can you please elaborate both options? I cannot copy resources, there are a lot of them and they and in two different projects. This simply does not scale. Regarding custom test runner what from I checked it takes only one resource location and my resources are in two projects.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this too.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do  this by customizing the resource paths loaded during the initialization of the [RobolectricTestRunner](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.html).

There's a good example of how to do this posted in this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29223625/3063884

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      includeAndroidResources = true
    }
  }
}
```

in app/build.gradle seems to be a preferred option to load resources for me.